# parsing a multipart email with mailcore

Tags: email, multipart, mailcore

I am new to mailcore. I am using it in objective-c, OS X, to parse email. I have an email I am trying to parse that is structured as a multipart/related. The first part of the multipart/related is a multipart/alternative. The multipart/alternative contains a text/plain part and a text/html part. Following that, the multipart/related contains a number of b64 encoded image/gif parts. When I use MCOMessageParser to parse this email, it returns a multipart/related as the main part, but the multipart/related contains only one part, which is text/plain and it consists of everything in the entire message as one big text blob. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you copy-paste the source of the message in a gist? Also, could you show the output of NSLog(@"%@", msgParser);?

Comment: Here is the output of NSLog(@"%@", msgParser);:

<mailcore::MessageParser:0x6080002d7a70 <0x608000134780><mailcore::Multipart:0x608000134780 related [<mailcore::Attachment:0x608000138740
mime type: text/plain
inline: 0
data: 16115 bytes
>]>>

I wasn't able to create a gist, but here is a dropbox link to a zip file: 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6248221/Agamemnon.eml.zip

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug: it's now tracked here: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/889. Thanks for reporting it.